# Does a varchar field's declared size have any impact in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, performance, varchar, disk-access

Is `VARCHAR(100)` any better than `VARCHAR(500)` from a performance point of view? What about disk usage?

Talking about PostgreSQL today, not some database some time in history.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

They are identical.

From the PostgreSQL documentation:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-character.html

> Tip:  There are no performance
>   differences between these three types,
>   apart from increased storage size when
>   using the blank-padded type, and a few
>   extra cycles to check the length when
>   storing into a length-constrained
>   column. While character(n) has
>   performance advantages in some other
>   database systems, it has no such
>   advantages in PostgreSQL. In most
>   situations text or character varying
>   should be used instead.

Here they are talking about the differences between char(n), varchar(n) and text (= varchar(1G)).  The official story is that there is no difference between varchar(100) and text (very large varchar).

Comment: I'm talking about VARCHAR(m) vs VARCHAR(n), not about VARCHAR vs CHAR, which is what you are pointing to.

Comment: Check again.  They refer to the THREE being identical.  I.e. performance of varchar(n) is same as text, which is varchar(LOTS).
The only difference between the THREE types is the padding and the length constraint.  Neither apply between varchar(100) and varchar(500), so they are saying they are the same.

Comment: Yes, they do mention all the three, but they only insist on two. I actually asked this question on SO exactly because I was not happy with that particular paragraph in the doc and I was looking for a more insightful explanation.
And no, TEXT is *not* the same as VARCHAR(LOTS). TEXT is stored outside the row. At least AFAIK.

Comment: As the referenced doc says, and as james2vegas re-iterates, any long field may be stored in a background table.

Comment: OK, seems two other people agree with this, so I guess it *is* right after all. Sorry, but the documentation is indeed not very clear, that's why I didn't want to count the documentation as an answer in the beginning.

Answer (score 12):

There is no difference between `varchar(m)` and `varchar(n)`..

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2008-07/msg00073.php

There is a difference between `varchar(n)` and `text` though, `varchar(n)` has a built in constraint which must be checked and is actually a little slower.

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2009-04/msg00945.php

Answer (score 11):

TEXT /is/ the same as VARCHAR without an explicit length, the text

> "The storage requirement for a short
>   string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte
>   plus the actual string, which includes
>   the space padding in the case of
>   character. Longer strings have 4 bytes
>   overhead instead of 1. Long strings
>   are compressed by the system
>   automatically, so the physical
>   requirement on disk might be less.
>   Very long values are also stored in
>   background tables so that they do not
>   interfere with rapid access to shorter
>   column values. In any case, the
>   longest possible character string that
>   can be stored is about 1 GB."

refers to both VARCHAR and TEXT (since VARCHAR(n) is just a limited version of TEXT).  Limiting your VARCHARS artificially has no real storage or performance benefits (the overhead is based on the actual length of the string, not the length of the underlying varchar), except possibly for comparisons against wildcards and regexes (but at the level where that starts to matter, you should probably be looking at something like PostgreSQL's full-text indexing support).